# Problems with runnable

Tags: java, android, runnable

I was advised to use this code to make my method execute after a definite period of time, i modified it a bit and now I have:

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        final long start = mStartTime;

        // Get the difference in ms
        long millis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;

        // Format to hours/minutes/seconds
        int mTimeInSec = (int) (millis / 1000);

        // Do your thing

        Location location = tracker.getLastKnownLocation(best);
        RetrieveAvgPower(location);

        // Update at the next second
        mHandler.postAtTime(this, 1000);//start + ((mTimeInSec + 10) * 1000));
    }
};
```

And I try to start and stop it with:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
         switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.start:
                    mStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);
                    break;
                case R.id.stop:
                    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
                    break;}}
```

However, there is an issue. First of all, my method sets text and writes a line to log file, but if I use the code above text is not being set, however all info is being written to log file automatically. Another thing is i can't stop runnable - after it starts executing program seems to be not responding and crashes if I try to press stop button. What am I doing wrong and how it can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't the last line of `run()` call `Handler.postDelayed()` rather than `Handler.postAtTime()`?

Depending on how event queues are implemented in Android you might be killing the thread by using the wrong one... you're basically repeatedly setting a Runnable to run at 1 second after the thread originally started, so no other events get to run.

Answer (score 1):

To stop your runnable you can just add something like this:

```
class A implements Runnable
{
private volatile boolean runTask = false;

public void run()
{
   runTask = true;
   while(runTask)
   {
      // Do your thing
      Thread.sleep(1000); // wait 1 second before "Do your thing" again
   }
}


public void stop()
{
   runTask = false;
}


}
```

As for the text not updating I didnt understand very well, is it in a swing gui that is not setting?

EDIT
Added a Thread.sleep(1000) at the end of the run method

EDIT by peer:
Moved the Thread.Sleep(1000) so that the Runnable will run once a second until stopped (instead of running continuously and then waiting 1 second after being stopped).